# Is there a way that I can set the default values of fields in a class so I don't have to specify a value on creation?

Tags: c#

I have this class:

```
public class ParamViewModel: BaseViewModel
{
    int _id;
    public int Id
    {
        get => _id;
        set => SetProperty(ref _id, value);
    }

    string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => SetProperty(ref _name, value);
    }

    bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get => _isSelected;
        set => SetProperty(ref _isSelected, value);
    }

}

public ParamViewModel[] STIVM { get; set; } = new[] {
        new ParamViewModel{  Id = 0, Name = STI.Zero.Text(), IsSelected = false} ,
        new ParamViewModel{  Id = 1, Name = STI.ZeroFive.Text(), IsSelected = false} ,
        new ParamViewModel{  Id = 2, Name = STI.One.Text(), IsSelected = false} ,
        new ParamViewModel{  Id = 3, Name = STI.OneFive.Text(), IsSelected = false} ,
        new ParamViewModel{  Id = 4, Name = STI.Two.Text(), IsSelected = false} ,
        new ParamViewModel{  Id = 5, Name = STI.Three.Text(), IsSelected = false} ,
        new ParamViewModel{  Id = 6, Name = STI.Four.Text(), IsSelected = false} ,
    };
```

Is there a way that IsSelected could be false by default?

Comment: Sure, by setting `_isSelected` to false on its declaration: `bool _isSelected = false`. However that is pointless, as `false` already *is* the default-value for bool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, by setting `_isSelected` to false on its declaration:

```
bool _isSelected = false;
```

In fact you could achieve the exact same when setting that value within the constructor of your class, as [vc 74](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51981814/2528063) pointed out.

However that is pointless, as `false` already *is* the default-value for `bool`.

Thus let´s see how it works for the int-property which should default to `-1` instead of the "normal" default of zero:

```
int _id = -1;
public int Id
{
    get => _id;
    set => SetProperty(ref _id, value);
}
```

Comment: So you mean if I don't set it to false at all that would be okay?

Comment: @Alan2 For bool yes. However if you want another default-value (e.g. `true` for `bool` or `-1` for `int`)  you have to provide it the way I wrote above.

Answer (score 1):

I think you actually mean call the property setter on construction:

```
public ParamViewModel()
{
    IsSelected = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the isSelected to

```
bool _isSelected = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `_isSelected` variable with `false`.

```
bool _isSelected = false;
```